# How can I make a flex-child in a column sit on the right side and not break the flow of the document?

Tags: html, css

I have this case here:
https://jsfiddle.net/07thcwd6/17/

```css
.layout-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-container {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-one {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-two {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-element {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 30px;
}

.bottom-element {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-parent">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child-one"></div>
    <div class="child-two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-element"></div>
  <div class="bottom-element"></div>
</div>
```

- I want the purple thingy to be on the right side of the screen and take as much width as the red box ( doesn't have to be exact, just close )
- I also want the blue box to extend to the orange box after that.

I know how to achieve that using grid but I currently have no idea how to do it when .layout-parent is flex. I also cannot move the purple box inside the red one as it would be a lot of hassle in the context of my app. Is there a simple way of achieving that, that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

An inelegant solution would be to set explicit height for `.child-one` and `.child-two` and make them align at `flex-start`; `.main-element` can then be positioned using a negative `margin-top` and `margin-left: auto`:

```css
.child-container {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child-one {
  height: 100%;
}

.child-two {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.main-element {
  margin: -30px 0 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --child-container-height: 100px;
  --main-element-height: 30px;
}

.child-container {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child-one {
  height: 100%;
}

.child-two {
  height: calc(100% - var(--main-element-height));
}

.main-element {
  margin: calc(var(--main-element-height) * -1) 0 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}


/* Demo only */

.layout-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-container {
  height: var(--child-container-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-one {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-two {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-element {
  background-color: purple;
  height: var(--main-element-height);
}

.bottom-element {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-parent">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child-one"></div>
    <div class="child-two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-element"></div>
  <div class="bottom-element"></div>
</div>
```

Another horrible way to do so is to make CSS ignore `.child-container` by setting `display: contents` so that we can `absolute`-ly position `.bottom-element`, effectively make it no longer a flex item, then set a fixed height for `.layout-parent` so as to make it `flex-wrap`-able:

```css
.layout-parent {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-container {
  display: contents !important;
}

.child-one {
  height: 100%;
}

.child-two {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.main-element {
  width: 150px;
}

.bottom-element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --layout-parent-height: 100px;
  --main-element-height: 30px;
  --bottom-element-height: 30px;
}

.layout-parent {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  height: var(--layout-parent-height);
}

.child-container {
  display: contents !important;
}

.child-one {
  height: 100%;
}

.child-two {
  height: calc(100% - var(--main-element-height));
}

.main-element {
  width: 150px;
}

.bottom-element {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(var(--bottom-element-height) * -1);
  width: 100%;
}


/* Demo only */

.layout-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-container {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-one {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-two {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-element {
  background-color: purple;
  height: var(--main-element-height);
}

.bottom-element {
  background-color: orange;
  height: var(--bottom-element-height);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-parent">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child-one"></div>
    <div class="child-two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-element"></div>
  <div class="bottom-element"></div>
</div>
```

They are both dirty, yet they works.